# On-page consent update trigger in Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform, cookieconsent

I've implemented Iubenda as a CMP on my website and I use Google Tag Manager to deploy most of my tracking scripts.

I've configured all my tags to require the right consent before firing.

But when a visitor hits my site, obviously the consent state is set to Denied by default to be GDPR compliant.  When my tags such as GA4 fire on an All Page Views trigger, they therefore see a Denied consent state and do not fire.  If the visitor accepts the right cookies, I see in GTM's debug/preview mode that there is an on-page consent update but no tags figure.  The tags only fire on the 2nd page view.

Is there a way to fire my basic tags on All Page Views OR an additional trigger that would fire when the right consent is granted so that I can track the landing page hit?